# Init js after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, href

I have a small Javascript used to swap images using a href links. Everything is OK except when I call those a ref inside the page using Ajax. I need to find a way to initialize again the script after calling new links.
Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$('a.thumbnail').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('href');

```
if (src != $('img#largeImg').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/,'')){
    $('img#largeImg').stop().animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src+'?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*(10*100)));
    }).load(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: '1'
        });
    });
}
return false;
```

});

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate the events.

Turn this:

```
$('a.thumbnail').click(function(){ /*...*/ });
```

into this:

```
$('#someWrapperContainer').on('click', 'a.thumbnail', function(){ /*...*/ });
```

Make sure you're using jQuery 1.7+

Comment: It worked! thanks, I am really bad with Javascript, I have been looking all day for this.. after all I know a little more and it works! thanks a lot